# Customizing facebook login button

Tags: css, facebook

I am looking to customize the facebook button in the facebook login widget. I solved this by making the original button's opacity to 0 and setting the background image of the iframe to the desired image. That worked. But the problem I am facing is that the click event on the button is taking the width of the original button rather than the new button. As a result the click event is not active on the entire button. I tried to overwrite facebook classes in my css file but that does not seem to work. Any ideas on how I can solve this

Comment: Why to use the facebook login button? Make any button of your choice and call facebook login on its click.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done/failed at. We can't really advise if we don't know see exactly what's not working.

Comment: bro ! iframe's style is not editable/changable. May be it will be possible in future. But you cant override its css, because iframe css comes from original server!

Comment: @Rahiil thanx bro! That's all I had to know

Comment: @SahilMittal how do you do that ? Making a different button and linking it to facebook click.

Comment: Just use js sdk and call `FB.login()` on your button click